# Installing Canopy on Linux without directories in home folder

Tags: enthought

When installing Enthought Canopy 1.0 using the `.sh` installer, it places a lot of stuff in my home folder, even though I chose a different installing location.

Part of this is some directory `~/canopy` with empty folders for scripts etc. - OK on that one, even though I would rather choose a different location for this, too.

The other part is `~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit` with binaries and libraries. I do not want these to be in my (backed-up) home directory.

How do I move this stuff somewhere else? I can see that there is an entry in my `~/.bash_profile` and at least also in `~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/pyvenv.cfg` pointing to that location. But are there more?

This should be made an option during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no officially supported way of doing this although there is a way to do it.  We aren't comfortable documenting this workaround in a public archive like stack overflow. If you can please send us a "suggestion" through Canopy's Help menu and we'll respond with the workaround.

Comment: As of Canopy 1.0.3 (June 2013), specification of the location of Canopy Python environments is supported, so here is no need for a workaround. On first startup, you will be prompted for the path, which you can put anywhere with an ASCII path. Also, if you already set up these environments, you can delete the file ~/.canopy/locations.cfg and restart Canopy, and you will be prompted for a location where they will be created fresh (not moved).